# BLE Android API 18 status 141

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I do device scanning. My Nexus 7 finds the device. After I trying to connect to the device, 
on

```
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {}
```

I have status  = 141. 
What does this code mean? I couldn't find this code in Documentation.
After that connection doesn't exists and no Services are discovered. 
Maybe someone has the same issue?

Comment: If it helps, 141 (0x8d or 10001101b) is just one bit different to 13 (0x0d or 00001101b) which is GATT_INVALID_ATTRIBUTE_LENGTH.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Yes. I had an idea about this, but this one bit make me doubt.I couldn't find any logical explanation of this one bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-4.3_r1.1/stack/include/gatt_api.h

Status 141 is supposed to be GATT_ENCRYPED_NO_MITM, although from my experience I have received this status for totally unrelated reason.

In my experience, if you make a gatt connection, and close it (BluetoothGatt.close()) before receiving onConnectionStateChange callback , you will then receive onConnectionStateChange with status = 141.

Comment: THank you for your answer.I know, that device has PIN code.. Interesting thing is that when I used Samsung SDK and Android 4.2.2, I could connect without PIN. Does it means that now I should promt connection with PIN code?

Comment: I discovered, that on Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3 Unofficial version, it connects with device and everything is ok.. I don't know is it something wrong with BLE in official version.

Comment: Just to clarify question. The problem is in Nexus 7 Second Generation. Still don't have any solution with it.

Comment: @dorafmon, no. Unfortunately not. Problem was definitely in Nexus 7, because on Nexus 4 app works correctly.

Comment: @Mike Did you turn on MITM on the other end of BLE?

Comment: @dorafmon Hm, it's interesting. No, I didn't turn on MITM, at least I don't know about that. That measn that it's not because of device...

Comment: I am seeing the same problem on my Nexus 7.  NO_MITM appears to stand for "No Man in the Middle". Looking for a complete answer.